# Wordpress page navigation

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I used to use a plugin that would give me the option to remove a page from the top navigation but still appear in the side navigation but for the life of me I cannot remember the name of it and I have too many pages for the all to be displayed in the top nav.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Exclude pages? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-pages/

Answer (score 1):

take a look at `wp_list_pages(include=$id)`
where $id = {list of comma seperated page ids}

here's the codex [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_list_pages)